# How to make a networked scanner appear as a local scanner?

Tags: windows-7, networking, printer, scanner

So we have a software system that we use here in our auto body shop that does all of our management etc.  It has the ability to scan documents directly into our work files.  We currently have a Lexmark multi-function printer/scanner/copier etc. that we use for everything here in the office.  We can scan with it using the Lexmark scanner utility which we have to initiate on each local computer when one of us wants to scan something.

**Here is the problem**, our office management software doesn't recognize the network scanner when we try to scan a document from within the program.  We get a "no scanner or image device found" error.  I am assuming it's because it only looks for a local scanner that would be connected via USB or something like that to the local user's machine.

**So here is my question**.....is there any way to make the network scanner APPEAR as a local scanner on my computer, as if it were plugged in via USB?

I have been searching the internet forever trying to find a solution and so far I can't!!
Short of buying another scanner and plugging it in via USB is there any hope out there?

Comment: If we are able to help you, it will be dependent on what OS the host computer is running. It is also important to know the brand/model of the scanner. Have you looked at the manufacture's web site for support information?

Comment: Sorry, It's on a Windows 7 64 bit system with a Lexmark XS736DE multi function machine.

Comment: AFAIK Windows dos not support sharing scanners over network, maybe that’s the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a Local Port which is pointed to the network device. These instructions are for adding a printer, but should be the same for the scanner.

In Windows Vista and 7:

1. Click Start > Devices and Printers.
2. Click Add a Printer on the top.
3. Select Add a local printer.
4. Select Create a new port, select Local Port for the Port Type, and click Next.
5. For Port Name, enter the network path to the printer by entering two slashes, the computer name or local IP address of the PC sharing the printer, and then the share name of the printer. For example “\dellpc\hpprinter” or “\192.168.1.100\hpprinter”
6. Select the printer and click Next. If the exact model isn’t listed, try the closest model number or a generic printer.
7. Follow the rest of the wizard.

Comment: -1 the question is about a scanner, not a printer.

Comment: +1 OP included the make/model of the scanner, which is a multipurpose device that includes "Color Copying, Color Faxing, Color Printing, Color Scanning, Color Network Scanning". We use many devices in my company like this one and can achieve cross-network scanning using the method CharlieRB posted.

Comment: Thanks CharlieRB....I just tried this method and although the machine shows up in my printers window and works just fine.....our management still can't "see" it as a local scanner device....I think I might be out of luck on this one! :-(

Comment: Did your manager(s) do the same on their machines? The manufacturer clearly lists the device as capable of Color Network Scanning.

Comment: Technically YES it is capable of network scanning utilizing the Lexmark Scan Back utility.....but the issue is it just won't show up on my local computer so that the management program will recognize it as a scanning device.....

Comment: @kinokijuf You could be a bit more constructive about your down votes. Do you know for a fact it will not work? I did state in my answer that "for adding a printer, but should be the same for the scanner". My experience is this will work for some devices. If you have a better answer, please post it.

Comment: I think I might have to just get a REALLY long USB cable and plug this machine directly into my machine. :-(  Thanks for all of the suggestions everyone.

Comment: Stand alone scanners aren't that expensive anymore. That might be another solution to consider.

Comment: @CharlieRB Scanners in Windows do not use ports.